# Time delayed script

Tags: time, delay, clock

Not a programmer by trade, and looking for some help. I have a working sheet in which we track jobs on. When they are completed we enter the word "Yes" in column 7 indicating the job is done. Our process is it set up so that 24 hrs later we try to remember to manually go in and hide the row. We want the row/job to be seen completed for that time length as an update. I've attempted using the trigger selection in Script Editor to automatically hide the row after 24 hrs., with no luck. Looking online it appears with the right script you can run the "hide row" script 24 hrs after the edit to column 7 is done. I have not been able to come up with the correct script to make this happen. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Are you referring to Excel ? What have you tried ? Do you have an error that you get ?? Did you google around ? Please also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm knew to this question and forum thing so sorry for lack of information. I am using Google Sheets. The "jobs" come in through Google forms. I have not really gotten errors, because I have gotten it to hide the job with triggers in Script editor at a designated time and every minute. The jobs are being marked completed around the clock. We were hoping to get it to be based on each job and a 24 hr time table. I have Googled triggers and understood enough to believe its possible but the coding seems to be over my head. Thought it might be a simple thing for someone that codes.

Comment: The thought is appreciated but you need to do some research and try to find sample scripts ... when you have errors or problems understanding the logic then post the script / code and ask for help with the section that bothers you. "Please code it for me" is not the intention of SO.